# How do I add the current date of input to a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a date (shown also to user) to each list input of the user in the web app I am working on.

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="todo">
    <header>
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
        <input id="new-todo" type="text" placeholder="Things you need to do...">
    </header>

    <section id='main'>
        <ul id='todo-list'></ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

and JavaScript is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function runBind() {
        $('.destroy').on('click', function(e) {
          $currentListItem = $(this).closest('li');

          $currentListItem.remove();
        });

        $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
          var $currentListItemLabel = $(this).closest('li').find('label');

          if ( $currentListItemLabel.attr('data') == 'done' ) {
              $currentListItemLabel.attr('data', '');
              $currentListItemLabel.css('text-decoration', 'none');
          }
          else {
              $currentListItemLabel.attr('data', 'done');
        $currentListItemLabel.css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
          }
            });
        } 

    $todoList = $('#todo-list');
    $('#new-todo').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === EnterKey) {
            $('.destroy').off('click');
            $('.toggle').off('click');
            var todos = $todoList.html();
      todos += ""+
                "<li>" +
          "<div class='view'>" +
            "<input class='toggle' type='checkbox'>" +
            "<label data=''>" + " " + $('#new-todo').val() + "</label>" +
            "<a class='destroy'></a>" +
          "</div>" +
        "</li>";

      $(this).val('');
        $todoList.html(todos);
        runBind();
        $('#main').show();

  }});
});
```

What should I add in the code to make that happen?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `Date()` to get the current date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested, get the current date using `new Date` and then you can use any one of the date formatting functions (or make your own):

- `toString()` gives `Tue Aug 16 2016 00:05:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`
- `toDateString()` gives `Tue Aug 16 2016`
- `toLocaleDateString()` gives `8/16/2016`
- You can also use `.getDate()`, `.getMonth()`, `.getYear()`, etc.

I would also recommend using jQuery to create your list item rather than raw HTML. You will run into issues the way you are currently doing it if you have a `<`, for example, in your todo name because it isn't escaped.

```
"<li>" +
"<div class='view'>" +
"<input class='toggle' type='checkbox'>" +
"<label data=''>" + " " + $('#new-todo').val() + "</label>" +
"<a class='destroy'></a>" +
"</div>" +
"</li>"
```

can be turned into

```
$('<li>').append(
  $('<div>').addClass('view').append(
    $('<input>').addClass('toggle').attr('type', 'checkbox')
  ).append(
    $('<label>').attr('data', '').text($('#new-todo').val())
  ).append(
    $('<a>').addClass('destroy')
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a date in a string you can use the javascript built in `Date` object.

For example:

To get today's date: `new Date().toDateString();`

To get a custom date: `new Date('01/01/1970').toDateString();`